# Compatibility problem in PHP?

Tags: php

I am facing an abnormal problem in a site. Where when I was trying to **login** with "*Chrome*", it is ***running fine***. But when I am trying to login with "**Firefox**" or "**Internet Explorer**" it is ***not allowing me to login***.

In **Firefox** it is showing **error** as :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0

And in **Internet Explorer** it showing :

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media
>   Center PC 6.0; AskTbFXTV5/5.8.0.12304)

What may be the possble reasons?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Those are not error messages, they are user agent strings.

Comment: @Dan : Can you tell me what may be the possible reasons?

Comment: It sounds almost like it's detecting your browser and making sure you're using Chrome on purpose.

Comment: It is impossible to say why you are having an explained problem with unknown code.

Comment: Plus PHP runs on the server, so you dont even *need* a browser to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an error message, but the user agent string of the respective browser. Search your code for something like

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

That may lead you to the position of where things go wrong.